# Control SPI input by manipulating 8 bit shift register with Linux GPIO subsystem

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, gpio, spi

I am working on 74hc595 device which is an 8 bit shift register on my custom board base on iMX8MP. There are actually 16 shift register which are daisy-chained. In input I have `MOSI` of my spi. There is a kernel driver `drivers/gpio/gpio-74x164.c`which support this device. I managed to create a device tree node:

```dts
&ecspi2 {
#address-cells = <1>;                                                                      
#size-cells = <0>;
fsl,spi-num-chipselects = <2>;                                                             
pinctrl-names = "default";
pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_ecspi2 &pinctrl_ecspi2_cs>;
cs-gpios = <&gpio5 13 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW &gpio2 0 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;                           
status = "okay";

  first_dummy_node@0{

  };

    74hc595@1 {
        compatible = "fairchild,74hc595";
        gpio-controller;
        #gpio-cells = <2>;
        reg = <1>;
        registers-number = <16>;
        enable-gpios = <&gpio1 15 GPIO_ACTIVE_LOW>;
        spi-max-frequency = <100000>;
    };
};
```

My driver is probed and under my `/sys/devices/platform/soc@0/30800000.bus/30830000.spi/spi_master/spi0/spi0.1/gpio/gpiochip368` directory I have a file named `ngpio` for "number gpio" which contain the value `128` which seems fair (8 bit * 16).

Now I wanted to know if it was possible to set directly the value of a GPIO. for instance `echo 1 > gpio368` and having in input the correct `MOSI` signal?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But the driver has to set all the bits every time anyway. So, the latency _in average_ will be SPI clock / 128 to set any bit. Note, it's better to use `libgpiod` and its tools instead of deprecated sysfs.